# JavaScript scrollTo method does nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So I am desperatley trying to get some scrolling functionality to work on a page. After not having a luck I decide to just stick `window.scrollTo(0, 800);` on my page to see if I could get any scrolling to happen. Nothing does happen. I have an accordion that expands and then I want to scroll to a specific element with in it. But for now I would be happy to just see the thing scroll at all. Anyone run into this?

Thanks!

Comment: I should note that I have tried the scrollTo JQuery plugin without any luck there as well. $.scrollTo(0,800);

Comment: In firefox in my address bar i just put javascript:window.scrollTo(0, 800); and it seemed to work.

Comment: ok, a. try it in different browsers, see if it works in any. b. try something like document.body.scrollTo. c. remember that javascript is case sensitive. Not sure if any of those will help, but you can try.

Comment: @luvat 
You are right! It works in this page but not in mine. I tried it in the address bar just as you did and it works here in S.O. but not in my project. Bazaar.

Comment: scrollTo does do something, just not on your page...  I'm guessing you will get little help without posting a url, your code, or at least providing some more details about your specific issue.

Comment: This actually another page that is being displayed within an iframe. that must be the problem here. How can I scroll within that frame?

Comment: Horrible question.  You provide no code, and we have no idea when your code is executing (if at all).

Comment: `scrollTo` was disabled for me because of a chrome plugin, not sure which.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem using jQuery method animate(). Here is an example of the implementation I went with:

```
$('#content').animate({ scrollTop: elementOffset }, 200);
```

The selector is getting the div with ID = "content". I am then applying the animate method on it with scrollTop as an option. The second parameter is the time in milliseconds for the animation duration. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I tried the other answers. This is the only one that worked for me too. Difference is I used `$('body').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 0);` where `top` is the variable containing the y-coordinate in integer.

Comment: @KimStacks A duration of 0 didn't work for me, but using 1 did.. can't believe how hard this is to do!

Answer (score 127):

If you have something like this:

```
html, body { height: 100%; overflow:auto; }
```

If both body and html have a height definition of 100% and also scrolling enabled, window.scrollTo (and all derived scrolling mechanisms) do not work, despite a scrollbar being displayed (which can be used by the user), when the contents exceed that 100% body height. 
This is because the scrollbar you see is not that of the window, but that of the body.

Solution:

```
html { height: 100%; overflow:auto; }
body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: To follow up here (many years later!), if you don't want to change your CSS in this case, you can instead use `document.body.scrollTo({ top: ... })` instead of window.scrollTo.

Comment: @btown thanx for saving my hrs

Comment: @btown thanks but it still doesn't work for me. `  document.body.scrollTo({
            behavior: 'auto',
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
        });` does not scroll on top of the page..

Comment: @KristiJorgji make sure it's actually the body that is scrolling when you scroll. It's possible you have another height: 100% component inside it that's actually the thing that is scrolling. Feel free to create a new question if you're still having issues!

Answer (score 54):

I fixed this problem with using a setTimout. I was using angularjs but maybe it can help in vanilla js too.

```
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 300);
        },2);
```

Comment: 2 milliseconds did not work for me, but 200 did. Thanks!

Comment: You saved me master

Comment: I used it and worked, but on slow networks it doesn't work any more.

Comment: 0s worked for me

Comment: It works, but can anyone explain why?

Comment: Can anyone explain why?

Comment: @JaberAlNahian the reason is that in some cases the document is still rendering, by adding a small delay its done loading and ready to scroll

Comment: Just for the record, it also worked in VueJs.

Answer (score 29):

Sometimes it's not just the CSS issue, for me the browser was the culprit. I had to solve it with this code:

```
if ('scrollRestoration' in window.history) {
  window.history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'
}
```

It lets developer take the ownership of scroll changes. Read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/history-api-scroll-restoration)

Answer (score 18):

This happened to me yesterday because I had `overflow: auto` on a div that was a child to `<html>` and `<body>`.

So I learned that for `window.scrollTo()` to work, you must have `overflow: auto` (or whatever, `overflow-y: scroll`) set on the `<html>` element.

I learned that for `document.body.scrollTo()` to work, you must have `overflow` set on `<body>`.

I learned you can also use it on any other element (if you want) using `document.querySelector('#some-container').scrollTo()`.

> In my case, I wanted `window.scrollTo()` to work, so I put the overflow CSS on `<html>`.

I'm surprised no other answers in here talk about "exactly which" element is scrollable. The root html element must be scrollable for `window.scrollTo()` to work. All my child elements downstream of `<html>` are set to `height: auto`.

My CSS is like this:

```
html { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: auto; }
body { width: 100%; height: auto; }
#app { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem.Focusing window before scrollTo worked for me.

```
window.focus();
window.scrollTo(0,800);
```

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR

`document.querySelector('#dummy_element').scrollIntoView()`

worked for me.

Explanation

I too was having an issue with the following

`document.querySelector('#some-container').scrollTo()`

`window.scrollTo()`

as @agm1984 mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58290951/6363451):

I then tried using:`document.querySelector('#dummy_element').scrollIntoView()`

that worked out for me.

Differences are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689339/6363451) in a better way.

Quick difference:

Element.scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element on which it's called into the Viewport of the browser window.

Window.scrollTo() method scrolls to a particular set of coordinates in the document.

Comment: This `scrollIntoView` actually worked for me as well using React Class Component.

Comment: This worked efficiently for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

For me setting the height of html and body to auto did the trick.

```
html, body { height: auto }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do on React, as I have a root element, as the first and outer most div on my page, I scroll to the top of that element.

```
      const root = document.getElementById('root');
      root.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem today and then I discovered that when I took out the auto generated doctype block:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

The window.scrollTo(0,800) started working along with the ExtJs scrollTo() function I was originally trying to use. I put the block back in and it stopped working. I don't know if this is what you were running into (2 years ago) but hopefully this helps someone else running into the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it had nothing to do with these answers. The problem for me first appeared after upgrading to Bootstrap 4 which converted a lot of my divs over to `display: flex`. It turns out JQuery's `scrollTop()` doesn't work so well with flex layouts.

The solution for me was to change my old code from:

```
$("#someId").scrollTop(1000);

// or

$("#someId").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 500);
```

to

```
$("html,#someId").scrollTop(1000);

// or

$("html,#someId").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 500);
```

The only difference is adding in the "html," before the div that needs to scroll.

Props to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56471079/491553) for helping me figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

In a React app, wrapping window.scrollTo with a setTimeout worked.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (scrollPosition > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition), 0);
    setScrollPosition(0);
  }
}, [scrollPosition]);
```

Answer (score 1):

check if your tag where is plugged your scroll get a CSS overflow[/-x-y] : hidden.
it fixed the bug

Answer (score 1):

In my case: `window.scrollBy(0,200);` is working.

I have no idea WHY  `window.scrollTo(0,200);` is not working and `window.scrollBy(0,200);` is working.

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.scrollTo(0, 800)` This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason both

```
   html,body {overflow: hidden}
```

have to be set, you could still scroll programatically with:

```
   document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight; // scrolls to bottom
   document.body.scrollTop = 0; // scrolls to top
```

Answer (score 1):

Try set html tag:

```css
html {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, is you page even big enough to scroll (even if it's in an iframe)? If not, or you aren't sure, make a giant div, then put something below it. Try scrolling to that.

Next, if your scrolling in an iframe, put your code on the same page as the frame source. That way you don't have to worry about getting the document or specific element in the other window, which can be tricky. Oh yeah, are you sure you are getting that part right? Stepping through with Firebug can help you with that.

Finally, put a breakpoint (using Firebug) on the line that is supposed to cause the scrolling to happen. Does it hit that breakpoint? If not, your code is not executing, and scrolling is not your problem.

(I answered this, with supporting context from [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173240/getting-anchors-offset-position).)

EDIT:

Scrolling is done window by window. If you are in a frame that can't scroll, then nothing will scroll. If you want that element in the frame to be scrolled to, get the offset of that element to its current window and add it to the offset of the containing frame. That should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, the page has enough height. I can see the scroll bar. I suspect that the problem has to do with the composition of this page. Because this site was created before the days of masterpages I have a main page that contains 2 frames. The first is a header nav bar and the other is a content area. I am assuming that this is the reason that the scrollTo method doesn't seem to work.

Comment: yeah, scrolling is done window by window. if you are in a frame that can't scroll, then nothing will scroll. and you will go crazy trying to figure out what's wrong. oh...

Answer (score 0):

If the scrolling has been done after a slide down, it should wait for the div to complete the animation like this

`$('#div-manual-lots').slideDown(200, function () { 
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000) 
});`

Answer (score 0):

Using the onunload property worked for me

```
window.onunload = function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a js function "scrollTo" with same name ... :O
Renaming fixed my problem.

Answer (score -2):

> When `window.scrollTo(x,y)` does not work on the console of the Browser, and the dom gets rendered after scroll, you can use this.

To scroll on **Splash** or any **javascript rendering service** execute below js:

```
document.body.style.height = "2000px";
window.scrollTo(0,2000);
```

In **Splash** you can do something similar to this:

```
  assert(splash:wait(10))
  assert(splash:runjs("document.body.style.height = '2000px';"))
    assert(splash:runjs("window.scrollTo(0,2000);"))
  assert(splash:wait(2))
  assert(splash:runjs("window.scrollTo(0,0);"))
```

Answer (score -4):

Take this code:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Methods/scrollToExample.htm
and save as an html file. Note how it hard codes a very large div larger than the browser's viewport. You probably need to add a content at the bottom of your page for the scrolling to even work.