# Updatepanel and scroll to top when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have the following setup:

*UpdatePanel -> Multiview -> 3 Views*

When I click on a button in one of the views, it should go to the next view and **slowly** scroll to the top.

Currently I've been trying the following methods, of which none worked (not even a quick scroll - it just stays still laughing at me ;-) ):

```
protected void PartOneContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckoutFlow.SetActiveView(PaymentMethodView);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "<script>scrollTo(0,0);</script>", true);
}
```

And the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "<script>$(window).scrollTop(100);</script>", true);
```

And the following where `ScrollToTop` was a function with the two different scripts from above:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;       
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ScrollToTop", "ScrollToTop()");
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174863/javascript-scrollto-method-does-nothing

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. I tried:
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "scroll", "$('#LeveringsDiv').animate({ scrollTop: elementOffset }, 200);", true);

Where leveringsdiv is a div in the bottom of the view with the button this is fun in.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Method

```
    private void SubirTelaTopo()
    {
        StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
        csText.Append("$('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), csText.ToString(), true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your doctype? Also setting the (css) height of html and body to 100 percent may help.

Comment: What do you mean about the doctype? I will test the 100%

Comment: I think it needs the transitional dtd: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: I have that, still gives a problem.

Comment: did you try an alert/ console.log to make sure your script is executed at all? As in: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "alert('hello world')", true);

Answer (score 0):

In your calls to [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx) you are passing in the script including `<script>` tags and also passing in `true` for the `addScriptTags` parameter. My guess is that the script block that is rendered in your page looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>scrollTo(0,0);</script>
</script>
```

I can imagine that this doesn't work in most browsers because of the nested script tags. Try removing the tags from your javascript snippet or passing `false` for `addScriptTags`

```
// Option 1
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
  "myscript", "scrollTo(0,0);", true);

// Option 2
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
  "myscript", "<script>scrollTo(0,0);</script>", false);
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, then you can consider solving this purely with client-side script, using the [`PageRequestManager.pageLoaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx) event:

> The pageLoaded event is raised after all content on the page is
>   refreshed, whether it was refreshed because of a synchronous
>   (full-page) postback or an asynchronous postback. You can use this
>   event to provide a custom transition effect for updated content.

Comment: I just tried this, and nothing happens. Any idea how to track what exactly gives a problem?

Comment: Have a look at the DOM after the update has happened using Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Firebug to see if you previously had two nested script tags. Also edit your question with any JavaScript errors you get in the JavaScript console.