# How can I prevent react-router Link to direct to the middle of a new view?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I use a simple Link as in:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

<Link
  className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
  to={'/path'}>
  Learn More
</Link>
```

the new view opens up at the middle of the page instead of at the top. How can I change that? Thanks.

Comment: which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: check the version of `react-router` in your `package.json` file.

Comment: "react-router": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",

Comment: Okay, in that case have a look at [react-router scroll to top on every transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition). You'll probably find an answer there.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Scroll Restoration](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration) from the React Router docs.