# Clicking <a> does not go to top of next page on some browsers

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, anchor, scrolltop

I have an  tag on page 1 that is near the bottom of the page. When clicked, the next page loads, but also near the bottom.

Happens when using Safari and Chrome on Windows 10. Doesn't happen on Chrome on Mac OS.

I originally tried it without the hash for a jump to the top, but added it after to try, and it still jumps to the bottom.

If it helps, I am using react-router

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-router scroll to top on every transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration. This must solve your problem. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me here. Just to add that the <ScrollToTopOnMount/> component did the trick!