# On React Router; why going to a new route doesn’t render the new route from the top?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am trying to figure out why if let’s say I am in the middle of the route/page `/current-path`, if I go to `/new-path`, then `/new-path` loads just in the middle or in the same position where I left the old path. The regular behavior should be if I go to a new route, the new route/page should load from the top.

[I recorded a video](https://monosnap.com/file/RvPNBrWfeaumZ4b3bz3YLybSNRTtFR) for you to see what I talk about.

If you see, in the video I go to a new route and if I want to go to the top, I have to scroll to it.

This is the component where I have my routes:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// … rest of the imports here

const App = () => (
  <ReduxProvider store={reduxStore}>
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/applications" component={Applications} />
            <Route path="/terms" component={Terms} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignupPage} />
            <Route path="/choose-profile" component={ChooseProfile} />
            <Route path="/profile-completion" component={ProfileCompletion} />
            <Route path="/investor-personal-profile" component={InvestorProfile} />
            <Route path="/startup-application" component={StartupApplication} />
            <Route path="/investor-application" component={InvestorApplication} />
            <Route exact path="/startup/:startup" component={StartupProfile} />
            <Route path="/search" component={SearchStartup} />
            <Route exact path="/investor/search" component={SearchProfile} />
            <Route path="/wiretransfer-instructions" component={WireTransfer} />
            <Route exact path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
            <Route exact path="/how-it-works" component={HowItWorks} />
            <Route exact path="/faq" component={Faqs} />
            <Route exact path="/:startup" component={StartupPublicProfile} />
            <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Footer />
    </Router>
  </ReduxProvider>
);

export default App;
```

I already tried to go to a new route with the `Link` component of react router, `<Link to="/about-us">About Us</Link>` and also like this =>

```
<button onClick={() => history.push('/faq')}>
    FAQ and Guides
</button>
```

So what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44438949/4819077

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-router scroll to top on every transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602724/4445142