# What's the right location to place "ScrollToTop" component?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-router

I'm following [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition) to implement a scroll to top every time there's a route change. The answer suggests creating a new component, `<ScrollToTop />`, which I did

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    }
  }, []);

  return (null);
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

I'm confused as to where to place such component, since my app is structured a bit differently. See the `index.js` and `App.js` files below.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <EWLoader />
    <ContextProvider>
      <Router>                       //tried placing below <Router>, didn't work
        <App />
      </Router>
    </ContextProvider>
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>                                    //tried placing above <Switch>, didn't work
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/EWadmin">
          <Admin />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/ewadmin-allbookings">
          <AdminAllBookings />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <EWHeader />
          <Middleware />
          {/* <EWPopular /> */}
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  )
}
```

I've also noticed `<ScrollToTop />` is destructuring an object's property `history` but I'm not importing or declaring it anywhere in `index.js` or `App.js`. Perhaps something should be done with regards to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve scrolling to top on page change:

### First solution

Modify your ScrollToTop component to this:

```
function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
    return unlisten;
  }, [history]); // make sure to list history as a dependency

  return null;
}
export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

Then add ScrollToTop just under your router. Now it scrolls to top anytime the history changes, for any page.

### Second solution

Modify your ScrollToTop component:

```
function ScrollToTop() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []); // No dependency

  return null;
}
// No need to use withRouter
```

Then add ScrollToTop under every Route component where you want this behaviour.

Comment: I'd like to add that I also deleted smooth scrolling from the css properties to make it work