# React Router scroll page to the top after transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navigation

In my application, when I change from one page to another the page is being kept at the same point it was on the previous page. I want to make it go to the top when I swap pages.

The react-router documentation has a solution: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration

I implemented it inside a component called `ScrollToTop` and wrapped my whole application with it, but everything inside it just don't get rendered. I have no idea why.

ScrollToTop:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

App:

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';

import Layout from './containers/Layout/Layout'
import MainPageConfig from './containers/MainPageConfig/MainPageConfig'

import ScrollToTop from './HOC/ScrollToTop'

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    
      <BrowserRouter >        
        <Layout>
          <ScrollToTop>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={MainPageConfig} />
            </Switch>
          </ScrollToTop>
        </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also tried the suggestions of this post: [react-router scroll to top on every transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition)

In both cases I get the same result.

How could I solve this?

P.S. I also tried to put `ScrollToTop` outside `Layout`, but nothing changes.

Comment: Can you define another Route and test again. E.g <Route path="/home" exact component={MainPageConfig} />

Comment: I already did that. Actually, my original application has multiple routes. I removed them just to make it simpler. But why did you think that? Maybe it can give me an insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try the below

```
 <BrowserRouter >        
    <Layout>
      <ScrollToTop />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={MainPageConfig} />
        </Switch>
    </Layout>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I don't understand. That's exactly the same code I posted in the question.

Comment: Switch is not wrapped inside the ScrollToTop component. Just tried that on a code sandbox.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. It worked. I just checked the documentation and that's indeed how it should be implemented, but I couldn't see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Since React Router 6.4, the [`ScrollRestoration` component](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration) can be used to scroll to the top after navigating to a new page (as well as restoring the old scroll position on returning to a previous page). It requires using a data router, such as one created by calling [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) (which is recommended for all new React Router web projects).

> This component will emulate the browser's scroll restoration on location changes after loaders have completed to ensure the scroll position is restored to the right spot, even across domains.

Render `ScrollRestoration` once in the application's root route component to use it:

```
import { ScrollRestoration } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
    return <>
        { /* content here... */ }
        <ScrollRestoration />
    </>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop({children}) {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

just pass children down the tree

Comment: This is a more concise implementation and it worked out better for me.