# React-router v6 window.scrollTo does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to fix the scrolling issue in React wherein when I was to scroll down to a certain point on the page, and then navigates to another page, that page will begin at the same scroll point as the previous page.

Here's what I tried:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router'

const ScrollToTop: React.FC = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('im scrolling')
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, [pathname])

  return null
}

export default ScrollToTop
```

And then imports it like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import ScrollToTop from './components/base/ScrollToTop'
import Apps from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ScrollToTop />
    <Apps />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

*Im scrolling* is printing in the console but the *window.scrollTo* is not working.
I also tried the *useLayoutEffect*, but the same result still not scrolling.

Comment: Does `window.scrollTo` work if you call it directly in dev tools? This may have something to do with the HTML/CSS markup and which elements are scrollable.

Comment: I tried to paste in the console but does not work either, it returns `undefined`, tried to use `document.getElementById("root").scrollTo(0, 0)` and still returns `undefined`

Comment: I see, I think `window.scrollTo(0,0)` returning undefined is expected behaviour. If the function `scrollTo` itself is undefined, that would be more problematic. If you're on Firefox and open up the dev tools you should be able to see which HTML elements are tagged with `scroll`. Then see if grabbing that `element.scrollTo(0,0)` works.

Comment: thanks @AsherLim , fixed it by targeting the specific parent container. It was the way I implemented the page layout, the scrolling content is within the child container. 

Comment: How did you target it ?

Answer (score 4):

Try grabbing `document.documentElement` or another specific element instead of `window`.

```js
const location = useLocation();
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, [location.pathname]);
```

Related: [react-router scroll to top on every transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185)

Comment: Asher Lim's comment under OP's post worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue with react-router v6 and using the following instead of window.scrollTo(0, 0) worked for me:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.body.scrollTo(0, 0); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this hacky solution that works with `react-router-dom v6`:

`ScrollToTopOnMout.tsx`

```
import { FC, ReactNode, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const ScrollToTop: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.getElementById('full-content')?.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default ScrollToTop;
```

`index.tsx`

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <ScrollToTop>
   <App />
  </ScrollToTop>
</BrowserRouter>
```

`App.tsx`

```
<div id="full-content">
  .....
  .....
  <Routes>
     .....
     .....
     .....
  </Routes>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those asking how I targeted the parent container. Here's what worked for me. (probably not a clean one but it works)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router'

const ScrollToTop: React.FC = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById('container-main') // id of the parent
    el.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, [pathname])

  return null
}

export default ScrollToTop
```

And use it like this

```
<div id="container-main">
  <ScrollToTop />
  ....
</div>
```