# How to scroll to top on route change with react router dom v6?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to scroll to top on route change with react router dom v6?

I have tried this, [react-router scroll to top on every transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition), which was my solution to make my page scroll to top on route change when I use `react-router-dom` v5. Now, I am using `react-router-dom` v6 and this solution does not work.

I tried [React-router v6 window.scrollTo does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65500832/react-router-v6-window-scrollto-does-not-work)  and does not work for me.

I tried https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7365, which is to use the `preload` prop to trigger the `scrollTo(0,0)`, also does not work for me.

Comment: Scrolling to top didn't really change between versions, what is your code doing that isn't working? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, `preload` isn't a prop in RRDv6.

Comment: Unfortunately, Something changed. No matter what I do or what code I implement, top: 0,0 is never reached in react-router-dom when the new page is rendered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71753162/2902063

Answer (score 19):

Well I'm not really sure what your layout looks like but inside your `<BrowserRouter />`  you can wrap your app in a wrapper and check for the location change in a `useLayoutEffect`. Then if there is a change you can scroll to the top. Here is a crude example.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-route-change-fqeqn5)

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

const Wrapper = ({children}) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location.pathname]);
  return children
} 

const Component = ({title}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{paddingTop: '150vh'}}>{title}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Wrapper>
        <p>Scroll the bottom to change pages</p>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Component title="Home"/>} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<Component title="About"/>} />
          <Route path="/product" element={<Component title="Product"/>} />
        </Routes>

        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <Link to="/product">Product</Link>
      </Wrapper>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: how about using `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` instead of `document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0)`?

Comment: @AMATEUR_TOSS Either way is fine.`window` just refers to the root and `document.documentElement` just refers to the <html> element. Both will work and they are basically doing the same thing. You shouldn't run into any issues using either one when using `scrollTo()` I don't think.

Comment: this does not work in 2022 July

Comment: @ManassehCodes It works just fine. Since you didn't add any context to your comment I don't know what you are doing wrong. I added a link to a codesandbox in the answer so you can see it working.

Comment: for a smooth scroll `document.querySelector('body').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});`

Comment: Why react router doesn't handle it?

Answer (score 8):

this article resolves this issue See it ->  https://www.matthewhoelter.com/2022/04/02/how-to-scroll-to-top-on-route-change-with-react-router-dom-v6.html

make **ScrollToTop** component

and then add this code init

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // "document.documentElement.scrollTo" is the magic for React Router Dom v6
    document.documentElement.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "instant", // Optional if you want to skip the scrolling animation
    });
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

and then import it in your App.js and now your issue is resolved

[see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKucv.png)

Comment: I used this solution and it works like a charm! 
NOTE: I had to import the `<ScrollToTop/>` on all the main components where I wanted to scroll to top on initial render. Even if you refresh it'll redirect to top of the screen.

Answer (score 5):

I use **ScrollRestoration**. I tried, if did't use ScrollRestoration component, window.scrollTo(0, 0) it didn't work.

```
 import { Outlet, useLocation, ScrollRestoration } from 'react-router-dom'
    function App() {
       const { pathname } = useLocation()
       useLayoutEffect(() => {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0)
       }, [pathname])
       return (
           <div className="App">
              <TopHeader />
              <Outlet />
              <Footer />
              <ScrollRestoration />
           </div>
        )
     }

     export default App
```

Answer (score 4):

To not only have the scroll position reset to the top when navigating to a new page, but also to maintain the old scroll position when returning to a previous page, use the [`ScrollRestoration`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration) component (since React Router 6.4). It requires using a data router, such as one created by calling [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) (which is recommended for all React Router web projects).

> This component will emulate the browser's scroll restoration on location changes after loaders have completed to ensure the scroll position is restored to the right spot, even across domains.

Simply render it once in the root component of your application. Here is an example with a functional component:

```
import { ScrollRestoration } from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
    return <>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <ScrollRestoration/>
    </>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This window function cannot be accessed in newer versions of react, it is better to use the useRef Hook.

```
const myRef = useRef<any>(null);
const executeScroll = () => myRef.current.scrollIntoView({inline: "center"});

useEffect(() => {
    executeScroll();
  }, [location.pathname]);
  
// YOUR COMPONENTS CODE
// I have my toolbar as the ref
<Toolbar ref={myRef}/>
```

This will scroll when using the useNavigator and the pathname changes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to **render** the component `<ScrollRestoration />` inside **your "root" component**, see the next code:

```
import { ScrollRestoration } from "react-router-dom";

function RootRouteComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <ScrollRestoration />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see more details: [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration)

Answer (score 0):

```
const scrollToPosition = (top = 0) => {
  try {
    /**
     * Latest API
     */
    window.scroll({
      top: top,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  } catch (_) {
    /**
     * Fallback
     */
    window.scrollTo(0, top);
  }
};
```

You can use the above code to scroll top.

```
const didMount = useDidMount();
const router = useRouter();
const { asPath } = router;
useEffect(() => {
    if (didMount) {
      scrollToPosition();
    }
  }, [asPath]);
```

And add the above code to the top parent component.

Answer (score 0):

i don`t know how but in my case ScrollRestoration works only in Layout, not inside App etc...

````
import { Outlet, ScrollRestoration } from "react-router-dom";

import { Header } from "../Header/Header.jsx";
import { Footer } from "../Footer/Footer.jsx";

export const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      <Footer />
      <ScrollRestoration />
    </>
  );
}; ``` 
i use "react-router-dom": "^6.21.2"
````

Answer (score 0):

i solved with custom hook

```
// useScrollTop.jsx
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function UseScrollTop() {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0, { behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [location]);

  return null;
}
```

in App.jsx or  Layout.jsx

```
import UseScrollTop from '@/hooks/useScrollTop';

const Layout = () => {
    UseScrollTop()
    return <>
        .....
    </>
}

export default Layout
```