# React navigation and routing problem with a multipage application

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project with multiple pages however if i scroll in one page and then use the navigation bar to navigate to another page the scroll is not undone so the page starts at the position of the previous scroll

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this question:

[react-router scroll to top on every transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition)

They asked the same question.