# After the React route is changed, scrolling remains

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Without specific code, I will briefly describe a phenomenon I encountered when using `react-router`. `<Link></Link>` to do a route jump, I scroll a certain distance in the current page to click one of the pages. `<Link></Link>` when the label contains a route, after the jump, the scroll bar is not at the top of the new page, but still in the same position as it was just before the jump, which is strange

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to scrolling behavior when using React Router's  component. By default, when you navigate using a link, React Router will try to scroll to the element with the ID specified in the URL hash.

If you want to ensure that the new page always starts at the top when navigating, you can use the `useEffect` hook in your page components to scroll to the top when the component mounts.

I add some example codeÏ:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Scroll to the top when the component mounts
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, []);
```

Comment: I now have this setup and it works fine, I just don't know if it's the default behavior of react-router or if there's a bug in my program， `React Router will try to scroll to the element with the ID specified in the URL hash.` I don't understand that

Answer (score -1):

The problem you're facing with the scroll position may be arises because the browser is maintaining the scroll position from the previous page.

"You can use the useEffect hook to scroll to the top of the page whenever the route changes."

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

If you're using BrowserRouter from react-router-dom, you can use its scrollToTop prop.

```
   <BrowserRouter scrollToTop={true}>
        
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Are you using version V6? I didn't work with the second method in my tests

Comment: You can get your answer from here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904185/react-router-scroll-to-top-on-every-transition

Comment: If the post/question is a duplicate then the correct action is to flag, or vote to close when you've the rep, as a duplicate.