# ScrollTo inside useEffect react component is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, scrollto

I am trying to scroll to the top on a component when its being rendered. My code looks like this:

```
const Terms = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    console.log("effect rendered");
  }, []);
  
return <>...</>
```

when I switch between 2 components it does not scroll to the top of the component. Even though `console.log` renders each time as expected but not the scroll.

Comment: Does the `scrollTo` work if you move it outside of the `useEffect`? Is there a reason this must happen on-render? It seems to make more sense to move this to the place that decides to render this Component.

Comment: are those 2 components the same component? like do you have 2 Terms pages?

Comment: No they are Terms and About, both running from Parent component under same Routes but they each have own Router

Comment: I took the scrollTo outsude useEffect and still the same issue @Halcyon

Comment: Does `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` work at all? There might be CSS reasons why the scroll isn't happening. Maybe the window can't scroll.

Comment: yes it works only if I click refresh button, but switching between Routes does not make it work

Comment: ```window.scrollTo(0, 0)``` works also if I have it inside a ```button``` as an ```onClick``` event @Halcyon

Comment: An `useEffect(..., [])` is equivalent to `componentDidMount` & is called once when the component is mounted. Are you sure the 'effect rendered' is printed each time ?

Comment: Yes each time it was rendered, I had another ```console.log``` with different text in the other component and both with rendering each time. @NiceBooks

Comment: Inspect to check if there are `<iframe>`s.

Comment: There arent any ```<iframe>``` @NiceBooks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119786/window-scrollto-in-react-components?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for my problem is:

```
  useEffect(() => {
     const element = document.getElementById('someId');
     element.scrollIntoView();
  }, []);
  return (<div id="someId"> ... </div>)
```

Thanks for everyone still for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I found a conversation and it seem that you have to give an `id` to the element you want to scroll to:

[window.scrollTo() in react components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119786/window-scrollto-in-react-components)

Your element:

`<div id="scroller">`

```
const scrollToTop = () => {
  document.getElementById("scroller").scroll(0,0)
}

<button onClick={scrollToTop}>Scroll to Top</button>
```

Put the scrollTop inside you `useEffect()` and it should work.

Comment: Didnt work tried it exactly this way with given Id

Comment: Somehow window.scrollTo only works if the page refreshes but not when just clicked to

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem came from my App.css file where I had set `scroll-behavior: smooth;` for all elements.

To make it so that the page will instantly go to the top, I had to specify in the scrollTo function that I wanted the scroll behavior to be instant. See this fix:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "instant",
    });
  }, []);
```

However, **if you do** want the smooth scrolling effect, the following code will achieve that.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), 100);
  }, []);
```

App.css

```
*{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```