# scroll to bottom doesn't work in componentDidMount react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my code? I don't see the scroll happening, no error. Perhaps props came after the scroll happens?

```
class MsgPanel extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0) // won't work
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.something}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You could drop this window function into timeout function with `1ms` delay, but I guess it's not the case.

Comment: @Kinduser what is the problem then?

Comment: Please check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

`window.scrollTo(0, 0)` is the top of the page, if you want it to scroll to the bottom of the page then you need to increase the value of the second argument.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 500);
```

Ok, so that was not the problem. If you are using react-router you could do it on the Route.

```
<Route exact onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} path="/mycomponent" component={MyComponent} />
```

Check out the discussion here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2144

Also, make sure your css it ok: [JavaScript scrollTo method does nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174863/javascript-scrollto-method-does-nothing/18573599#18573599)