# ScrollTop setInterval not Working on Angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, scrolltop

I have a tried and tested bit of code that has always worked well for me. But when i tried it in Angular 6, it was failed.

I want to make auto scroll down without button click in my page (contain table).

> index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Dashboard</title>
   <base href="/">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon_new.ico">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
   <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.48.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />   
</head>
<body>
   <app-root></app-root>
   <script src="./src/assets/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="./src/assets/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> app.js

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
 setTimeout(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 8000);
 },2000);
},2000);
```

> activity-dashboard.component.html

```
<div id="contain" class="row">
 <div eds-tile class="xl-12">
    <eds-tile-title>User on Shift</eds-tile-title>
    <eds-table id="table_scroll" [columns]="tablePresetColumns" [data]="tablePresetData" [modes]="['compact', 'dashed']"></eds-table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help solve my problem ? Thanks...

Comment: don't use jquery, let's start there ;)

Comment: what do you mean sir @AJT_82 ?

Comment: why Don't you try `ViewportScroller` from angular, instead of using jQuery with Angular here https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller

Comment: check the value of `document.body.clientHeight` and `window.innerHeight` , if you body height is set 100% (<= height of your screen) and inner content height is more than that, then scrollTo does not works

Comment: @Pardeep I cannot figure out how to use the function of viewportscroller

Comment: they are same, my document.body.clientHeight = 551, and my document.body.clientHeight = 551 sir @Rajan . So what should i do ?

Comment: A bit off-topic but.. @PardeepJain Whoa, thanks for the link, I have totally missed ViewportScroller, didn't know it existed. Big thanks, very useful! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Seems some of the function can be replaced as OP using jQuery like `getScrollPosition` etc. Anyways Cheers! #HappyLearning

Comment: @tonjel if you got scroll in your page, then this might be the case

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174863/javascript-scrollto-method-does-nothing/54799200#54799200

Comment: @tonjel It's just discouraged to use jQuery with Angular. Usually there is "an Angular way" of doing the same :) And if you are planning to use jQuery to manipulate the DOM, it's a bigger no-no. Here's a post I found when rushing through google: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/92lpy4/reasons_not_to_use_jquery_angular/e36n5a2