# react scrollTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, scroll, react-redux

I am new to the react. Here I have is a table which has some `td`, now on click of the button I add one more td in that table. Now, the table is also scrollable,so , what I want is that table scroll should be at top when we add a new row. So, that user will come to know easily that the row has been added .

I tried is ,

I have a container,

**JobList.js**

```
constructre(props){
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.operationType) {
      this.props.changeOperationType(this.state.operationType);
    }
    if (!this.props.jobs) {
      this.props.fetchUserJd();
    }
    this.myRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }


render() {
   return(
      <UserJobsTabel
              jobList={filteredList}
              sortAscending={this.sortData}
              sortCountAndScoreAscending={this.sortNumbersAscending}
              addNewRow={this.addNewRow}
              isRowAddingEditorVisible={this.props.isRowAddingEditorVisible}
              removeRow={this.removeRow}
              refer={this.myRef}/>
   )
}
```

**UserJobsTable.js**

```
<div className="table-responsive">
    <table>
    <thead>
     <tr className="text-center">
            <th></th>
            <th scope="col">Technology<i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon"></i></th>
            <th scope="col">Total Resumes<i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon"></i></th>
            <th scope="col">Job Title<i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon"></i></th>
            <th scope="col">Total Score<i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon"></i></th>
            <th scope="col">Average Score<i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon"></i></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody className="text-center" ref={props.refer}>
 </tbody>
//remaining
   </div>
```

So, Here I am getting the error that scrollTo is not a function.

So, is there any way to do this ? Or what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where was `this.myRef` defined? To use the new ref system, in your constructor you have to call `this.myRef = React.createRef();`

Comment: I have added it in the constructor

Comment: I have @dotconnorupdated the questtion

Comment: @tanmay  sorry I  did not get you

Comment: instead of calling `scrollTo` function assign `scrollTop` param. LIke `this.myRef.current.scrollTop = 0`

Comment: So, I added this and it worked. actually, on click of the add button in that I have to call this.myRef.current.scrollTop = 0. then it has scroll to top.

Comment: Can u tell me why it worked ?

Comment: actually, I am passing refer as a props to the UserJobsTable.js where that tbody is

Comment: @ganesh see if `this.myRef.current.getNode().scrollTo(...)` works?

Answer (score 1):

use `this.myRef.current?.getNode().scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 0})`

Answer (score 0):

can you please try to change ref={props.refer} from tbody to the div of table?
like this :
`<div className="table-responsive" ref={props.refer}>`

as far i know react's scroll to works with div or it needs some plugins like jquery oe window

anyway you can also try this (in the last case fyi this is not a good option):
document.body.scrollTo()

for further reference:
[JavaScript scrollTo method does nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174863/javascript-scrollto-method-does-nothing/18573599#18573599)

Comment: that's why the last option would be document.body.scrollTo()

Answer (score 0):

because `this.myRef` get the instance of `UserJobsTabel`. You can forwarding refs instead.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html